# Merge two lists based on two or more filters

Tags: java, list, lambda, merge, stream

Hi If i have to merge two lists based on two or more filters can you guys let me know how to do it. I tried but not able to figure out. thank you in advance. Please find the code i have tried below -

```
Stream.of(entity.getUsers(), existingEntity.getUsers())
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toM`enter code here`ap((AuthorizedUsersEntity::getLightHouseId),
                                d -> d,
                                (AuthorizedUsersEntity x, AuthorizedUsersEntity y) -> x == null ? y : x))
                        .values());
```

i wanted to filter out using another property too. please find the example below how i am expecting the merged list to be

UpdatedUsers - [{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"}, {"c":"3"}],

existing users -[{"a":"2"},{"b":"3"}, {"c":"4"},{"d":"5"}}]

Merged list - [{"a":"1"},{"b":"2",},{"c":"3"},{"d":"5"}]

Comment: what does "merge based on filters" mean?

Comment: Can you provide any code that you tried?  Or at least input data and expected output?  This should help make your question a bit less enigmatic.

Comment: This is the code i tried - Stream.of(entity.getUsers(), existingEntity.getUsers())
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap((AuthorizedUsersEntity::getLightHouseId),
                                d -> d,
                                (AuthorizedUsersEntity x, AuthorizedUsersEntity y) -> x == null ? y : x))
                        .values());

Comment: So i have 2 lists - UpdatedUsers - [{"a":"1"},{"b":"2", "c":"3"}], existing users -[{"a":"2"},{"b":"3", "c":"4",{"d":"5"}}].. and i need the combined list as below -

Merged list - [{"a":"1"},{"b":"2",},{"c":"3"},{"d":"5"}] and i need to filter based on two properties not just one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier to use the `Map` here ...

```
var map = HashMap<String,String>()
for(var updatedUser : updatedUsers) {
   map.put(updateUser.key, updatedUser.value)
}

for(var existingUser: existingUsers) {
  map.putIfAbsent(existingUser.key, existingUser.value)
}

// The merged list now contains the results
var mergedList = new ArrayList();
for(vap entry = map.entrySet()) {
  mergedList.add(new User(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
}

var result = mergedList.stream().filter( <firstCondition> ).filter( <secondCondition> ).collectToList();
```